# Replacing ID's in a CSV string with a class

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV string that contains a list of ID's.

```
1,2,5,8
```

I also have a corresponding List that contains a Car class as follows. The id of the car corresponds to that of the ID in my CSV list and the list contains all known Cars.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Car {
   private int id;
   private string model;
}
```

What I want is a CSV string that instead of having ID's, has the model parameter instead.

I have used a StringTokenizer to split my CSV string, then created a for loop to iterate over the split string, building a new string by checking the ID against the value in the list. The solution works fine, but feels less than elegant. I am thinking it could be better written using streams, but cannot do so.

```
String[] cars = carsCsv.split(",");
String carsNames = "";
for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
   for (Car car: carList) {
      if (StringUtils.equals(cars[i], car.getId().toString())) {
         if (i == cars.length-1) {
            carsNames += car.getModel();
         } else {
            carsNames =+ car.getModel() + ", ";
      }
   }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the relevant code that you're currently using

Comment: Updated with my code sample

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with expressing the algorithm using loops as you have.   I recommend a couple of small changes for efficiency:

```
String[] carsIds = carsCsv.split(",");
StringBuilder carsNames = new StringBuilder();
for (String carId: carsIds) {
   int carIdInt = Integer.parseInt(carId); 
   for (Car car: carList) {
      if (carIdInt == car.getId()) {
         if (carsNames.length()>0) {
             carsNames.append(", ");
         }
         carsNames.append(car.getModel());             
      }
   }
}
return carsNames.toString();
```

It is more efficient to convert the carID to an integer once, and then use an integer comparison when walking through the inner loop.

It is more efficient to use a StringBuilder to collect the characters because otherwise the string manipulations were repeated converting to and from strings automatically under the covers.

The other answer uses "map" but what you have to realize is that map is running a loop inside itself.  The map to convert them all to integers is actually a loop and constructing an array for the results, and then map to find the model is doing another loop.  There is no magic: the algorithm has to loop through the data.   I personally don't see any problem with making the loop explicit.

A hand made loop benefits from optimizations of using local variables instead of having to reconstruct an array on every step.   It is a personal choice.

Comment: I agree with the fact that he'll always have to loop, either with a `for` or a `stream`. However, one of the interesting point of the Stream API is that it reduces the boilerplate code and emphasis the concept of *Behavior Parametrization*. Therefore you can replace all the noise from the `for` and `if` blocks and other statements with english words.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I find streams approach very intellectually interesting.  It is kind of kewl that you can do it without loops.  I have also learned that clever code is not always the most maintainable.  Every Java programmer knows the semantics of `for` and you can count on 100% familiarity.  The `stream` while interesting is not well known, and programmers are likely to make mistakes or waste time looking for it.  If efficiency is similar, I always favor clear, well known semantics over clever but obscure.  The exception is if you used `stream` a LOT, then maybe everyone would know it well.